# having trouble drawing rectangle on camera preview

Tags: android, overlay

I'm trying to draw a rectangle overlay on top of a camera preview. I've got the overlay in a FrameView and the onDraw() is called successfully but the rectangle never shows up. I've searched around and tried different solutions but none have worked for me so far.

This is what I have for FrameView

```
public class FrameView extends View {
    private Paint mFramePaint = null;
    private final String TAG = "FrameView";

    public FrameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mFramePaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mFramePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mFramePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        Rect drawRect = new Rect(300,300,300,300);

        canvas.drawRect(drawRect, mFramePaint);
    }
}
```

This is my xml for the camera preview activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eyesee.CameraPreviewActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview">

    <com.example.eyesee.FrameView
        android:id="@+id/frame_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code snippet from my camera preview activity for attaching the camera preview

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private final String TAG = "CameraPreviewActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_preview);

    mCamera = MainActivity.getCameraInstance();

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout)   findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RelativeLayout child views are drawn in order,
you need to add the preview below your view:

```
preview.addView(mPreview,0);
```

your rectangle is size of 0 - new Rect(left,top,right,bottom)

```
Rect drawRect = new Rect(0,0,300,300);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't fix the issue. I'm still only able to see the camera preview and nothing shows up for the view.